# HTML reads as invalid, moving HTML <head> contents to <body>

Tags: html, magento, dom

I have a website which (whilst looking at the source) seems to output completely valid HTML, however running it through an HTML validator or inspecting element in any browser shows that it's being rendered with all the  contents jumped down into the `<body>` tag.

You can see it on any page at the below link

http://www.violetdarkling.com/

The only weird thing I can think of is that it goes thru [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com), but I've tried turning that off (including various combinations of the services turned on/off plus completely bypassing it, and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the page starts with the three characters “a3a”, hex codes 33 61 33. You can see this e.g. by using Rex Swain’s [HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) with Display Format set to Hex.

This is invalid and may thoroughly confuse programs, e.g. so that they interpret the character data as implicitly opening the `body` element.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I thought there must be something weird up there but didn't have any way of finding it!

Any idea what could be causing that?